# oracle create a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

In oracle database: I tried the following query:

```
    CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER  myTrigger
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON product
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO h_product
    (
        H_PRODUCT_ID,
        PRODUCT_ID     
    )
    VALUES
    (
      seq_h_product.nextval,
       :new.product_id
    );

END
```

when I execute, I get this error:

```
3:56:45  [UPDATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 4098, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-04098: Déclencheur  'NEILA.myTrigger' non valide. Echec de la revalidation
```

I execute :

```
select object_name
from dba_objects
where object_type = 'TRIGGER'
and status = 'INVALID';
```

=> I get myTrigger in the list !
why is it invalid?

Comment: Sounds like it didn't compile properly or that it is missing a dependency.  Are both h_product and product tables in the neila schema or does the neila schema have permissions to insert/update/select from the product and h_product tables?

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Comment: using dbvisualizer how can I execute show errors?

Comment: @xQbert, I have the necessary permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as the following as you have missed `:new.product_id`

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER  myTrigger
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON product
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO h_product
    (
        H_PRODUCT_ID,
        PRODUCT_ID     
    )
    VALUES
    (
      seq_h_product.nextval,
       :new.product_id
    );

END;
/
```

Comment: I tried this but I get another error:
 [Error Code: 4079, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-04079: spécification de déclencheur erronée

Comment: invalid trigger specification

Comment: @neila Can you post your modified trigger code by editing your answer and make sure `h_product` table and columns mentioned in trigger code does exist.

Comment: I do, yes I m sure they exist

Comment: @neila In your edited trigger code, you have missed semi colon `;` after `END`. See my answer.